# Function returning <= with one or two arguments

Tags: r

How to interpret this function?

```
  g <- function(x,y) y <= x^2
```

How to call the function? g(2) or g(2,3)? What will it return?

Comment: have you tried `g(2)` or `g(2,3)`?

Comment: can you give a little more context?  (Is this a homework question?)

Comment: I was trying to understand a monte carlo simulation, see http://www.r-bloggers.com/probability-and-monte-carlo-methods/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<=` is a comparison operator, where you are comparing whether the Left-Hand Side (LHS) is **less than or equal to** the Rigth-Hand Side. The answer to which will be either **TRUE** or **FALSE**.

In your example, the function is returning the result of

```
2 <= 3^2
[1] TRUE
```

You will call the function like `g(2,3)`, as both `x` and `y` are required.

```
g <- function(x,y) y <= x^2

g(2,3)
[1] TRUE
```

The arguments `(x, y)` are required because you haven't set any default values for them. To do this you define the values in the arguments of the function

```
g <- function(x = 2, y = 3) y <= x^2   ## assigned default values 
g()                                    ## using the default values
[1] TRUE
```

---

Having the function all on one line is a shorthand of the more explicit

```
g <- function(x, y){
    return(y <= x^2)
}

g(2,3)
[1] TRUE
```